# Drawing semantic maps in LaTeX

Tags: draw, overleaf

So I'd like to draw a semantic map in my article. Where semantic frames are in some order organized and groupped by different colored boxes of lexemes. As an example of what I want, I can attach one, which I drew manyally. So, the question is whether it's possible to create the same in LaTeX (in Overleaf).

In this case every box is a rectangle, but sometimes it's needed to draw polygon-boxes.

P.S. By the way, may be there is a separate service, where user gives groups of values, and the code, combining equal values, generates a map like this. I haven't found anything like this.

[image: Russian semantic map of 8 Armenian lexemes, meaning different kinds of fogs and mists.]

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) I would just drtaw this using TikZ directly in LaTeX. It is not much of a hassle. But you'll have to look into TikZ yourself as this is not a "do this for me" service.

Comment: @daleif  Wow, I've seen something about TikZ previously, but i thought it has like narrow focus on plots and formula visualizations. Now I found it's 1000-pages manual and realized how much wrong I was. Gonna read hard. Much thanks!

Comment: Oh, no, you can do lots and lots of things using TIkZ. Here just focus on learning to do nodes with text, with and with out frames around them, learn to access the corners of nodes, learn to use the `calc` library to tikz to do calculations with coordinates. Then this is not too hard to draw. I like this much more than point and click programmes as I have total control of what is being done and where.

Comment: @daleif I don't think one even needs `calc` here. IMHO `positioning` to position a number of nodes with an appropriate `text width` relative to each other and then `fit` to draw the frames around groups of those should do it. Or instead of `positioning` use `matrix`, in particular for the legend.

Comment: @marmot, might be, for a beginner, I think knowing the `calc` lib is very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but perhaps a start, which shows you how to

1. arrange the texts in a Ti*k*Z matrix,
2. use fit with different `inner sep`s to draw the frames,
3. use matrix again to produce the legend.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\def \mytext{blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah}
\matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes={text width=2.5 cm},row sep=5mm] (mat) {
\mytext & & & & \\
\mytext & & & & \\
\mytext & & & & \mytext\\
 & \mytext  & & & \\
& \mytext & \mytext & & \mytext\\ 
\mytext & & \mytext & \mytext &\\
};
\node[draw=blue,fit=(mat-2-1) (mat-3-1),inner sep=1pt]{};
\node[draw=red,fit=(mat-2-1) (mat-4-2) (mat-3-5),inner sep=3pt]{};
\node[draw=black,fit=(mat-2-1) (mat-5-5) (mat-6-4),inner sep=5pt]{};
\matrix[matrix of nodes,right=5mm of mat-1-1.east] (legend){
|[cyan]| 1. duck & |[red]| 3. koala \\
|[blue]| 2. rabbit & |[green!60!black]| 4. anteater\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]